# Unit Test Stored Proc with H2 Database

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2, jdbctemplate

I am unit testing a stored proc which is returning 2 result set.

How I can do this with H2? 
I have created a a Alias but when I am returning a Array of result set it is not working.

```
    public static ResultSet[] createDummyStoredProc(
      Connection connection,
      String one,
      String two,
      String three,
      String four) {
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet[] resultSets = new ResultSet[2];
    ResultSet resultSet=null;
    ResultSet resultSet1=null;
    try {

      statement = connection.createStatement();
      resultSet =
          statement.executeQuery(
              "select nm_feature, in_feature, id_feature as id, in_ui from tempui");

          resultSet1 =
          connection.createStatement().executeQuery(
              "select t.nm_sp from tempbusiness t");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    resultSets[0]= resultSet;
    resultSets[1]= resultSet1;
    return resultSets;
  }
```

I am using Spring boot and JDBC Template( as I didn't get any solution in JPA to handle multiple resultset)

**Note:** It is working as expected with one resultSet returned in place of array but I want to test it for 2 result set